# Extra indentation is added to code blocks inside .razor files in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2019

Extra indentation is getting added to code blocks in .razor files in Visual Studio 2019.

Below are expected behavior and current behavior with the indentation issue (the pipe character "|" denotes the cursor position).

Before pressing ENTER:

```
@if (true) { | }
```

After pressing ENTER (expected behavior):

```
@if (true)
{
  |
}
```

After pressing ENTER (current behavior):

```
@if (true)
      {
        |
      }
```

As can be seen above, six space characters are added before open and close curly brace characters, as well as before the cursor's correct position.

My global tab settings are as follows:

- Indenting: Smart
- Tab size: 2
- Indent size: 2
- Insert spaces: true
- Keep tabs: false

I tried resetting all settings and trying different combinations of settings, but couldn't resolve the issue. When I enable "Keep tabs", the same issue surfaces as extra added tabs instead of extra added spaces.

I have also been researching online (mostly in SO and MS forums) but couldn't find a solution yet. I submitted a detailed bug report to Visual Studio with screenshots and screen recordings, but the issue hasn't been fixed.

These extra spaces have become such an annoyance that I'm even considering to make a switch to the Rider IDE. I tried it with the same tab settings and .razor files didn't have this issue.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as well in VS 2019. However, this only happens if I do like you said and type `@if (true) { | }` then press enter. Instead if I only type `@if` then press `tab` twice, the extra indents do not appear. Give that a try.

Comment: @ShawnOrr That makes things better for now, thank you. I just hope that MS prioritizes this issue since they seem to put the Blazor app model at the front lines these days. Another slightly off-topic question but still related to Blazor development in Visual Studio is: How do you deal with Blazor lifecycle method snippets being broken? Do you type them out or have a fix? If you don't have this issue and have no idea what I'm talking about, as I hit TAB to activate a lifecycle method snippet, the current line and sometimes lines before the current line gets deleted, snippet doesn't get written.

Comment: I don't have any experience with Blazor unfortunately. I would suggest creating another question for this topic and add the `blazor` tag to it.